# Include table header when writing matrix to file

Tags: matlab, file-writing

I write a matrix from Matlab to a file using `dlmwrite`:

```
A = [1,2,3; 
     4,5,6; 
     7,8,9];

dlmwrite('output.txt', A, 'delimiter','\t');
```

This gives me this `output.txt`:

```
1         2         3
4         5         6
7         8         9
```

Now I would like to add a header to have the following result:

```
columnA   columnB   columnC
1         2         3
4         5         6
7         8         9
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: [A. Visser's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32092015/1011724) is a good way to go, but you might also want to have a look at the table data type which [has this functionality built-in](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/writetable.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building upon [A. Visser's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32091926/include-table-header-when-writing-matrix-to-file/32092015#32092015), I found the following solution:

```
A = [1,2,3; 4,5,6; 7,8,9];
out = fopen('output.txt','w');
fprintf(out,['ColumnA', '\t', 'ColumnB', '\t', 'ColumnC', '\n']);
fclose(out);
dlmwrite('output.txt', A, 'delimiter','\t','-append');
```

Comment: Good  solution, it works fine! Notice, you avoid using `dlmwrite` by inserting `fprintf(out,[repmat(['%f\t'],1,length(A)),'\n'],A.')` before `fclose`.

Answer (score 2):

```
Headers = ['columnA',   'columnB',   'columnC'];
dlmwrite('output.txt', Headers, 'delimiter','\t');
A = [1,2,3; 4,5,6; 7,8,9];
dlmwrite('output.txt', A, 'delimiter','\t','-append');
```

using the argument `'-append'` makes `dlmwrite` stick everything at the end of the existing file. This way the first `dlmwrite` writes a header in the file, the second `dlmwrite` writes the matrix below the header in the same file.

Comment: The code you suggested gives me the following result
    c o l u m n A c o l u m n B c o l u m n C
    1 2 3
    4 5 6
    7 8 9
There is a delimiter between every character of the header.

Comment: I forgot the commas. Either try Headers = ['columnA',   'columnB',   'columnC']; or Headers = {'columnA',   'columnB',   'columnC'};
I'm not sure the second (with cell-structure) writes correctly, but it might work.

Comment: There are still delimiters between every character when I use commas or curly braces.

Comment: `dlmwrite` is for numeric data and treats every index as a separate value. `fprintf` is the more appropriate choice.