# save and sprintf in loop not printing

Tags: matlab, printing, save, printf

I'm running a loop code for many files in folder: e.g. 1.txt,99.txt,107.txt.. and i want to print results from loop, which is 6 variables with n number of rows to a text file with the 'names ' of files from each iteration. That is result file will be names 'result_1.txt' and inside the text file printed 6 variables as columns with around 1000 rows received from loop. I'm doing this:

```
save(sprintf('result_IterCase%d.txt', IterCase), num2str('date'),'length','class1','class2','Number file','Number file2','-ascii');
```

I get warning:

```
Warning: Attempt to write an unsupported data type to an ASCII file.
Variable 'date' not written to file.
```

From reading comments I feel like sprintf and save not doing good job and I'd better be off using fprintf.

When I used this code just for one instance I used fprintf and it printed well.

```
fprintf(fileId, '%f\t %f\t %f\t %f\t %f\t %f\r\n', date,length,class1,class2,Number file,Number file2);
```

However I don't know how to use fprintf for loop for many file. 
any help of better way of using sprintf or example on using fprintf would be much appreciated!!

thank you in advance!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32095269/5211833 might help you. Try the '-append' tag.

Comment: @A.Visser thank you. I was wondering shall I use whole dlmwrite command with '-append' in conjunction with frptinf?

Comment: @mil Have you tried to remove `'date'` just to see if it works? My point is that you get a warning concerning date. If it works without date you should investigate, why date can not be written to an ascii file. By the way, `'date'` is the same as `num2str('date')`.

Comment: @mil use fprintf for strings and use dlmwrite for numbers. You can use both on the same file and swap between them depending on the class that needs to be written. Just create the file once, then use '-append' to write things to it.